# Сортировка выбором, уменьшение количества итераций внешнего цикла

Tags: c#, сортировка

Всем Привет!

Есть функция которая делает сортировку методом выбора, всё хорошо работает, но как я понимаю можно уменьшить количество итераций внешнего цикла, в данном случае можно сделать обмен меньшим количеством действий?

Может быть кто знает как это сделать? Подскажите пожалуйста!?

```
    public static void SelectionSort(int[] array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            int minElement = array[i];
            int minElementIndex = i;

            for (int j = i + 1; j < array.Length; j++)
            {
                if (array[j] < minElement)
                {
                    minElement = array[j];
                    minElementIndex = j;
                }
            }

            int temp = array[i];
            array[i] = minElement;
            array[minElementIndex] = temp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Если вам надо ускорить сортировку, то вы не тем путем идете - вам нужен другой алгоритм, например, сортировка слиянием или быстрая сортировка. Если же вам надо просто уменьшить колво итераций, то находите за один внутренний проход не только минимум, но и максимум, и двигайтесь от обоих краёв массива в центр - тогда внутренний цикл на каждой итерации будет на 2 уменьшаться, а не на 1.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Нужно именно сделать сортировкой выбором
На сколько я вас понял нужно сделать через двухстороннюю сортировку выбором Double selection sort ?
но я правильно понимаю что при такой постановки задачи речь идёт про ускорение внутреннего цикла? а не внешнего? или они оба ускорятся?

Comment: Все верно,  я про двухстороннюю сортировку. Я не знаю что конкретно вы имеете ввиду под ускорением циклов, потому вы сначала напишите двухстороннюю, добавьте ее код в вопрос, поглядите на нее и если будут конкретные вопросы - спрашивайте.

Comment: При одновременном поиске минимума и максимума у вас в два раза уменьшится количество итераций обоих циклов, но надо аккуратно обработать перемещение элементов, т.к. вы не можете переместить их одновременно и возможно ситуация при которой переместив в конечную позицию минимальный элемент, вы измените начальную позицию максимального, или наоборот. Этот случай нужно отдельно проверять между между перемещениями.